# Is it possible to use ES2015+ modules instead of AngularJS dependency injection?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, es6-modules

Is it possible to get around AngularJS's dependency injection and use ECMAScript 2015+ modules instead?

My goal is to never have to call `angular.module` on controllers, services, and factories. I can do that for those easily, but if I want to access `$http` and other similar providers, I only know how to get to them via dependency injection. Is there a way to pull them in with an `import` statement or from the `angular` instance?

Answer (score 0):

Controller is just a function, factory is just a function, Component is just an object.

controller.js:

```
export default ['$scope', function($scope) {...}]
```

component.js:

```
export default {...}
```

module.js:

```
import com from 'component.js'
import contr from 'controller.js'
angular.module('module', []).component('c1', com).controller('contr1', contr);
export default angular.module('module').name
```